# Tumblr API to get posts from all users which have the same tag

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

Is it possible to get all posts from Tumblr users which have the same tag? 
For example, I want to get posts from [this](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/web+design) category (tag). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the API documentation [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method).

- http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=web+design

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "search" API for Tumblr